# How can I increase row vertical spacing in a table without affecting inner arrays?

Tags: tables, spacing, arrays

The methods I am aware of for modifying vertical spacing in a table are `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<length>}` and `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{<length>}`. However, these commands affect the arrays inside the table as well.

Is there any command similar to `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}` but for row spacing?

This is the code for my table, and I'd like to increase the spacing between the matrices, as they look too close to each other.

```
    \begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
             Description & Symbol & Value\\ \hline
             State-Space Matrix & $A$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 1.0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.0\\ 0 & 744.7 & -40.32 & 0\\ 0 & -1152.0 & 40.32 & 0 \end{array}\right)$\\
             State-Space Matrix & $B$ & $\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 61.63\\ -61.63 \end{array}\right)$\\
             State-Space Matrix & $C$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1.0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1.0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$\\
             State-Space Matrix & $D$ & $\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0 \end{array}\right)$\\
             Open-loop Poles & $OL$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -9.187+25.78{}\mathrm{i} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -9.187-25.78{}\mathrm{i} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -21.95 \end{array}\right)$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Pre-Lab Parameters}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative using the `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccSc}
        \hline
             Description & Symbol & Value\\ \hline
             State-Space Matrix & $A$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 1.0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.0\\ 0 & 744.7 & -40.32 & 0\\ 0 & -1152.0 & 40.32 & 0 \end{array}\right)$\\
             State-Space Matrix & $B$ & $\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0\\ 61.63\\ -61.63 \end{array}\right)$\\
             State-Space Matrix & $C$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 1.0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1.0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$\\
             State-Space Matrix & $D$ & $\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 0 \end{array}\right)$\\
             Open-loop Poles & $OL$ & $\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -9.187+25.78{}\mathrm{i} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -9.187-25.78{}\mathrm{i} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -21.95 \end{array}\right)$\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Pre-Lab Parameters}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The package `cellspace` worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: When I included the vertical lines as $|c|c|$, it removed all the spacing added in-between the matrices. Would there be any way to avoid this issue? Thank you.

Comment: To be honest, based on the information you provided so far, I can't really deduce what you changed on comparison to my answer. Probably it would be better to ask your request as a follow up question including a complete and compilable MWE.

Answer (score 2):

A `tabstackengine` approach.  Column gap set with `\setstacktabbedgap{}`, and extra matrix vertical gap set by optional argument of `\addstackgap` (found in `\zz` definition).

If you wish to adjust the row spacing of the inner arrays, use `\setstackgap{L}{<length>}` to define the baselineskip.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,array}
\setstacktabbedgap{1.5ex}% INTER-COLUMN GAP
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\newcommand\zz[1]{\addstackgap[5pt]{$\parenMatrixstack{#1}$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
        \hline
             Description & Symbol & Value\\ \hline
             State-Space Matrix & $A$ & \zz {0 & 0 & 1.0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.0\\ 0 & 744.7 & -40.32 & 0\\ 0 & -1152.0 & 40.32 & 0} \\
             State-Space Matrix & $B$ & \zz{ 0\\ 0\\ 61.63\\ -61.63 }\\
             State-Space Matrix & $C$ & \zz{ 1.0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1.0 & 0 & 0 }\\
             State-Space Matrix & $D$ & \zz{ 0\\ 0 }\\
             Open-loop Poles & $OL$ & \zz{ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & -9.187+25.78{}\mathrm{i} & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -9.187-25.78{}\mathrm{i} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -21.95}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Pre-Lab Parameters}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `tabstackengine` package worked just fine. Thank you for your time!